# How to scale flink on an un-keyed stream

Tags: apache-flink, scale, stream-processing

I have a relatively basic use case. My data lives in a few 100 kafka partitions and I need to pass the events through a map operator before I send them to a custom HTTP sink.

For performance reasons the events need to be batched into groups of n messages, and ideally the batches should be flushed after a few seconds. It seems like a good solution would be to use a tumbling processing time window with a purging trigger if the count of events meets my max batch size.

The issue is that I need to scale this job up to handle 100k events per second. To get the windowed batching Flink wants me to use a key by statement. I've attempted using a few different keys but ran into balancing issues, and the keys also break the operator chaining. Is there a good way to use the window functions without a key and still have the operators distributed across multiple task managers?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a custom sink, one approach would be to stick to this simple job graph

```
kafka -> map -> sink
```

and do the batching in the sink. Sinks have access to processing time timers, and they can have managed state, which you'll want to use to store the batches (assuming you care about providing exactly-once guarantees). The second half of the Flink Forward talk on [Integrating Flink into your ecosystem - How to build a Flink connector from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCMfbGv38u8) is a good resource.

Otherwise, you'll probably want to go ahead with a keyBy. To get the keys to balance nicely, you might simply add a field to each event that you populate with a random number, and use that as the key. (But do NOT do something like `keyBy(random.nextLong())`, as it is crucial that the keys be deterministic.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact, this is what I’m doing currently but I need to start collecting metrics from the http requests. The best approach I could come up with is to turn the sink into a process function that outputs a stream of response times times and error codes. To get the process function to support a timer I have to use a keyed process function (still on v1.8). I like your idea of adding a new field for the key. I’ll try that out